# When a variable is assign by :, what does this mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw a piece of code, which looks like this.

```
a=3
test: a=2
print(test) # test = 2
print(a)    # a = 3
```

I don't know why `a` remained unchanged, and test is assigned successfully.

Also, I found that if I do not define `a` in advance, there will be errors.

I don't know what the keyword of the syntax is as well as the purpose.

I hope that you can answer the question.

Comment: When I try this code, I get a syntax error in Python 3.5.2.

Comment: python 3.7 works fine

Comment: You've probably seen the more familiar syntax: `name: str = "someone"`

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That notation was added 3.6+ (If you haven't see the duplicate answer yet)